# LLVM::predecessors could return duplicate basic block pointers

Tags: llvm

We used the `predecessors()` to get the predecessors of a basic block based on LLVM's IR. The code is like:

```
for (llvm::BasicBlock* pred_bb : predecessors(cur_bb)) {
   printf("prev_bb=%p\n", pred_bb);
}
```

However, we found that the `predecessors()` could return duplicate basic block pointers. The output of above code could be:

```sh
prev_bb=0x56407eaee190
prev_bb=0x56407eaee190
prev_bb=0x56407eaee190
prev_bb=0x56407eaee190
prev_bb=0x56407eaee190
```

If there exists better methods to get the predecessors of a basic block? Or we have to check the duplicate predecessors before usage?

Comment: We further found these duplicate predecessors apear in ``switch`` instructions. An github issue has mentioned this situtaion (https://github.com/NETMF/llilum/issues/76).

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is known and desired (although I personally don't see it as overall desirable).

It happens for some switch statements and could happen for conditional branches too. Put briefly, there is one incoming entry in `predecessors()` for each outgoing target in `switch`/`br`, *even if the targets are not unique*.

If block baz ends with `br i1 %bar, label %foo, label %foo`, that is, a conditional branch that branches to block %foo in both cases, then that block has two predecessors, which you may think of as "block baz, outgoing condition false" and "block baz, outgoing condition true". If your code doesn't distinguish between outgoing conditions, this will not be what you want. But you can filter quite easily.